# Metafor forest plot shows incorrect confidence intervals for odds ratios

Tags: r, confidence-interval, r-forestplot, metafor

I'm trying to plot odds ratios and corresponding 90% confidence intervals, which I have previously obtained from a proportional odds model using package brms. I've made vectors containing the odds ratios obtained from the model (medians of the posterior samples; x), as well as lower (ci.lb) and upper (ci.ub) confidence interval bounds, respectively, and used the following code to make a forest plot:

```
x <- c(6.587028, 10.67589, 1.578881, 1.396755, 5.447785, 1.852427, 1.828179, 1.725313, 1.526206, 1.993046, 1.191804, 0.7648945)

ci.lb <- c(2.682959, 4.196124, 0.6783311, 0.547960, 2.011936, 0.7649611, 0.7492622, 0.6538183, 0.5299715, 0.8348141, 0.4814904, 0.2945799)

ci.ub <- c(17.843931, 29.200081, 3.7121095, 3.612463, 15.466248, 4.6075681, 4.3162345, 4.3404646, 4.3962568, 4.7397496, 2.9739579, 1.9560032)

forest(x, ci.lb, ci.ub, annotate=TRUE, showweights=FALSE, 
       header=headers, top=3, steps=5, 
       refline=0, digits=2L, xlab="Odds ratios", 
       slab=labels, efac=1, pch=15, col)
```

However, the confidence intervals on my forest plot do not correspond to those given in my ci.lb and ci.ub vectors. This is the plot I get:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The forest plot the OP is showing comes from the `metafor` package, not the `meta` package. The latter loads `metafor` and the function being used when running `forest(x, ci.lb, ci.ub)` is `metafor::forest.default()`. If you take a look at the documentation for this function (https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.default.html), you will see that the first five arguments are `forest(x, vi, sei, ci.lb, ci.ub, ...)`. Hence, you are passing the `ci.lb` and `ci.ub` vectors to arguments `vi` and `sei`, which makes no sense. So use `forest(x, ci.lb=ci.lb, ci.ub=ci.ub)` to make sure these vectors are passed to the right arguments. Overall lesson here is not to rely on position matching of arguments.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, thanks for your response! This is actually what I also expected was going wrong, but when I try running the code as you suggest, I get the following error, which I find confusing since I understood that the ci.lb and ci.ub would override vi and sei: Error in forest.default(x, ci.lb = ci.lb, ci.ub = ci.ub, annotate = TRUE,  : 
  Length of 'vi' (or 'sei') does not match length of ('ci.lb', 'ci.ub') pairs.

Comment: I just ran the code both with the CRAN version of metafor and the devel version and it works without any problems. Please make sure you are using a current version of metafor.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, I am using the latest versions of both R and metafor. I cleaned the code I originally used (in my initial post), however, and indeed it now works perfectly. Specifically, I just used this: forest(x, ci.lb = ci.lb, ci.ub = ci.ub, header=header, xlab="Odds ratios", slab=labels). Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using `forest` from the package `meta` . If I load that library I get the exact plot as you:

```
library(meta)
forest(x, ci.lb, ci.ub)
```

[image]

This function requires an object of class `meta`. For what you have now, maybe this will work:

```
library(forestplot)
studynames = paste0("study",1:length(x))

naming = list(
       "study"= studynames ,
        "odds ratio[95% CI]" = paste(round(x,digits=2),
        "[",
        round(ci.lb,digits=2),"-",
        round(ci.ub,digits=2),"]")
          )


forestplot(labeltext=naming,mean=x,lower=ci.lb,upper=ci.ub)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed, this looks much more like what I need! Thank you very much!